# Prevent directory listing and files for specific user

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions, file-access

I have a folder (/files) and I have tons of files there that users can download. I want users to be able to download their files only and no be able to see others people file.

For example:

User A can only view and download:

```
- file1.doc
- file2.jpg
```

User B can only view and download:

```
- file3.txt
- file4.jpeg
```

User C can only view and download:

```
- file1.doc
- file2.jpg
- file3.txt
```

My idea was to put all files in the same folder so all users knows where to go. My question is: Can I use .htaccess or should I build a PHP scripts for this? What about security (which one is more secure)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it an open directory, to start with? What you could do is create a subfolder for each user, put their files in there and then assign appropriate permissions in .htaccess for said folders. However, this would require some security integration with your OS (i.e., users would have to have accounts on your machine, not just your web application)... A quick and dirty -- and insecure -- alternative would be to prepend all uploaded filenames with the username (e.g., 'file1.jpg' uploaded by 'foobar' could be named 'foobar.file1.jpg', for example), then it's just a case of your PHP script returning only those files with the respective username and perhaps stripping that part out when displaying (or again, you could use folders, as long as your script can create a new folder per user, when one doesn't exist). Another option, which is *slightly* more secure is to create a hash of the file and usernames in a database, rename all uploaded files with this hash and then query the database appropriately.

The best solution would definitely be OS managed accounts, a I first mentioned, but it entails more overhead.

Comment: can you elaborate on the hash the file?

Comment: When a user uploads a file, your script could rename the file using some unique key. For example, you could use the SHA1 hash of the username and filename, plus some salt (e.g., the upload time); so, if `foo` uploaded `bar.jpg` on `201109291510`, then you could rename that file to `SHA1('foo bar.jpg 201109291510')` and, in a database, store this key, with the username and original filename in plaintext...

Comment: ...Then, when displaying a file listing to your user, you could query the database `WHERE user='foo'`, showing the plaintext filenames on screen, but linking to the hashed filenames (which would be hard for anyone to brute force).

Comment: It goes without saying that the more indeterminate the salt is, the harder it will be for an attacker to locate a specific file. Note that, while it's unlikely, your code should also check for clashes in case the SHA1 (or whatever) produces the same hash under different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Build a PHP script where you use [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) to send the file to the browser. This way you can restrict access for individual files, and use the authentication system you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use either htaccess or PHP for this. Neither are more secure, as far as I know, that the other - though done wrong both can permit access where none is intended!

PHP might be marginally better, since you have more flexibility (in terms of integrating it with other PHP authentication, say) and you can put the folder outside the usual web root, which is good practise anyway.